# Network and data security for small online businesses?

Tags: web-application, network, databases, physical, intrusion

What is the most efficient way of protecting small online business from outside threats. Everything too much expensive is not a solution.

I've been looking for good web application firewall and at the same time not expensive, since the business is using applications, but other than WAF, I need hardware security.

Comment: Bit of a broad question tbh. but broadly speaking, in a small business, you've got to make sure you're not tempted to skip things like user education, security policy etc.  You could have the best hardware layer in the world, and it could be for nothing if the CEO is plugs in a comprimised USB he found on his desk.

Comment: I totally agree, but lets say that the employees are well educated and the only threat can come from outside attacks on network or web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use open source  solutions for that and try to make it perfect based on your environment.

For IPS you can use Suricata engine.

For Firewall you can use PFSense or ClearOS.

For WAF you can use IronBee or [wafw](http://sourceforge.net/p/wafw/wiki/Home/)

For SIEM you can use AlieanVault OSSIM.

All the above products are free and open source, but some of them has missed feature and need to be paid to go with pro edition.

I hope this fits your requirements.

Rami,